# Is there a native way to share a link?

Tags: unity, python, gwibber

Is there some sort of API available in Ubuntu that allows you to share a link with Twitter, Facebook etc?

I've found this: https://code.launchpad.net/~ken-vandine/+junk/gwibber-api-examples but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need gir1.2-gwibber-0.2 installed.

Here is a basic example:

```
from gi.repository import Gwibber
s = Gwibber.Service ()
s.send_message ("This is a status update", None, None, None)
```

Description of the parameters (which you can likely ignore):

```
"""
  send_message: Posts a message
  @message: The message to post to Gwibber as a string or None
  @id: The gwibber message id or None
  @action: The action or None (reply, private)
  @account_id: The ID of the account to post from or None
"""
```

And for a more detailed example you can see the [tutorial](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/ubuntu-developer-stack/social-networking/adding-social-networking-support-to-your-app/).